# How to create dependency between two parallel processes running simultaneously

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have two parallel processes running simultaneously, actually one process shows a user interface and another one runs script in the backend. If the user closes the window, i also want to stop the backend script from running.

Parallel processing code is shown here:

```
def run_parallel():
    p1 = Process(target=new_sniff_window)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=new_sniff)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

How can i abort process p2 when p1 exits?

Comment: Pass the process ID of p1 as a parameter to p2. p2 then needs can then either query the status of p1 or join() on p2 as well. No idea on how to do that in Python.

Comment: I believe it's pretty feasible but need to see how do the crucial functions declared and work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run p2 as a deamon process

```
p2.daemon = True
```

p2 will terminate, if the mean program terminates. Or if p2 is a child process of p1, it will terminate if p1 terminates

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon